# Is there an HDMI switcher that will auto switch with two or more "always ON" devices?

Tags: xbox-360, ps3

Is there an HDMI switcher that will auto switch with two or more "always ON" devices? My 360 and PS/3 have some kind of output that make the device appear to always be on. So I have to manually switch between them.

Does anyone have or heard of a switch smart enough to work with these "always on" devices?

Answer (score 3):

I have a PS3, 360 and Wii (using the Wii2HDMI adapter) connected using this switch here:
http://www.dealextreme.com/details.dx/sku.27521

Auto-switching works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Any good AV receiver will do this.  I'm guessing you want something cheaper though (they start at around $200).

As for just a switch, something like [this](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=hdmi+switch&cid=18344023088345279157&ei=wAmmTJ2cBZe2iwSRtbhU&sa=title&ved=0CBcQ8wIwATgA#p) will work.